# Determining the size of subspaces $\{S_1,...,S_m\},\{T_1,...,T_n\}$ given their relative orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra

In my problem, I have two inputs: a binary matrix $M$ of size $m\times n$ and an integer $k\geq 1$.

Let $S_i$ and $T_j$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^k$ with $1\leq\dim(S_i)\leq k$ and $1\leq\dim(T_j)\leq k$ for all $i=1,...,m$ and $j=1,...,n$.

The matrix $M$ indicates how the subspaces $S_i$ and $T_j$ must intersect.
When $M(i,j)=0$, it means that $S_i$ and $T_j$ are orthogonal to each other, that is, $S_i\perp T_j$.
When $M(i,j)=1$, it means that $S_i$ and $T_j$ are not orthogonal, that is, $S_i\not\perp T_j$.

> My question is the following: given an integer $k$ and a matrix $M$, what can we say about the dimensions of the subspaces?

For example, it is obvious that when $M(i,j)=0$, it leads to the inequality $\dim(S_i)+\dim(T_j)\leq k$ meaning that we can obtain stronger upper bounds:  $\dim(S_i)\leq \color{red}{k-1}$ and $\dim(T_j)\leq \color{red}{k-1}$.

My problem concerns more particularly the following example with $k=3$ and $M=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$,

I am pretty sure that this matrix implies to have $\dim(S_i)=\dim(T_j)=1$ for $i,j=1,...4$ but I am not able to prove it.

Maybe, with the special sparsity pattern of $M$ (multiple zeros per row/column), would it possible to show that it implies $\dim(S_i)\leq k-2$ and $\dim(T_j)\leq k-2$ for $i,j=1,...4$?

Thank you very much for any advice!

Comment: Also posted to math.stackexchange, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967391/determining-the-size-of-subspaces-s-1-s-m-t-1-t-n-given-the-fact without notification to either site.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example we easily get that all 8 subspaces are non-zero (else we would have all-1s row or column), and   none of $S_i$ contains another $S_j$ (since there exists a subspace orthogonal to $S_i$ but not to $S_j$.) So, if, say, dimension of $S_1$ is at least 2, the subspaces $S_1,S_2$ should span the whole space, thus $T_1$ is orthogonal to everything, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

(comment) 
Correct me if I am wrong but if one takes 
$$
\begin{array}{c}
S_1 = span(e_1, e_4) \\
S_2 = span(e_1, e_3) \\
S_3 = span(e_2, e_4) \\
S_4 = span(e_2, e_3) \\
T_j = span(e_j)
\end{array}
$$
with $e_j$ being the standard basis vectors,
one would obtain the same $M$, right?

Comment: Yes, you would obtain the same $M$. But in my example, since $k=3$, I am working with subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and you are using $e_4$...

Comment: O, my bad. Need to think more.

Comment: If $dim (S_i) = 1$ and  $dim (T_j) = 1$, would we get from the first line of $M$ that $T_1 = T_4$ as they are 1-dimensional subspaces with one-dimensional intersection with 1-dimensional $S_1$? But then they all will be the same $S_i = S$, $T_i = T$ and a contradiction appears. Where have I mistaken this time?

Comment: Ok, now I think it is my fault. I am really sorry. For my example with all dimensions equal to $1$, my solution is $S_1=span(e_3)$, $S_2=span([1,-1,1]^T)$, $S_3=span(e_2)$, $S_4=span(e_1)$, $T_1=span(e_3)$, $T_2=span([1,1,0]^T)$,$T_3=span(e_1)$ and $T_4=span([0,1,1]^T)$. Actually, I mean that when $M(i,j)=0$, we must have $S_i\cap T_j=\empty$ and when $M(i,j)=1$, we must have $S_i\cap T_j\neq\empty$.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by $\empty$? there is always a 0 in the intersection of two subspaces. For your example, $S_1 \cap T_4 = 0 = S_1 \cap T_3 = 0$, but $M(1,3) = 0$ and $M(1,4) = 1$.

Comment: I changed the description. When $M(i,j)=0$, $S_i$ and $T_j$ must be orthogonal to each other and when $M(i,j)=1$, they must not be orthogonal.

Comment: Suppose, $dim(S_i) > 1$ for some $i$.Then $dim(S_i)=2$ (or there are no orthogonal vectors). Let's say it is $S_1$. Then $T_2 = T_3$ since there is only one orthogonal direction to a plane in 3d. But then the second and third columns of $M$ must be absolutely the same and they are not. Contradiction. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, really nice! Thank you very much for your help, the issue of this example is solved! Now I am wondering if having two zeros per row/column in any matrix $M$ implies the upper bound $k-2$ on the dimensions of the subspaces...

Comment: If all $S_i = S$ and $S$ is $(k-1)$-dimensional, then all the rows of $M$ are the same and any number of zeros in the row can correspond to the $T_j$'s which are all equal and $1$-dimensional. So there should be a stronger requirement for $M$. Like if there are zero's in one of the rows of $M$, then the corresponding columns must be the same.

Comment: I see, nice counter example! So the difference of the sparsity pattern of the rows/columns may play a role.